# Python: Saving filenames incremently

Tags: python, opencv

I am trying to process a bunch of files and trying to save them with  incremental files names.

For example the files name should be: `S1-T1-C.00001.jpeg, S1-T1-C.00002.jpeg,...., S1-T1-C.03021.jpeg and so on`

The code I am currently using is:

```
i = o
for imagePath in imagePaths:
    ....
    cv2.imwrite('S1-T1-C.%5d.jpeg' % (i),image)
    i += 1
```

The output file names I get are something like this: `S1-T1-C.    1.jpeg, S1-T1-C.    2.jpeg, .....,S1-T1-C.  100.jpeg,..., S1-T1-C. 3021.jpeg`

How can I add the zeros to the filename?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add a leading zero to the format specifier: `'S1-T1-C.%05d.jpeg' % (i)`

Comment: Wow. It was as simple as that. I was so over thinking this. Thanks man

Comment: I love how all it took was one character